# Should it be a new commit? Or just commit --amend?

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm working with Gerrit. I have already done a commit. After few days I noticed that I need to modify some files. I also created a new folder including some pictures.

Now my question is, should I really need to make a new commit?
I believe it is enough to do a commit --amend and then push it to review!

Comment: If the commit you want to amend is not yet merged into a shared branch, then yes you can still change it without bothering anyone.

Comment: Whether you make a new commit or amend a previous commit is usually up to the dev's discretion/opinion-- are the new set of changes better conceptualized as their own set of deltas or as part of the previous set of changes?  That said, I would caution against getting too comfortable using commit amend in lieu of new commits as a matter of habit-- I have seen devs who never made new commits, just amended previous commits, sometimes to rather unfortunate affect and with unintended consequences.

Comment: If the "about to be amended" commit has already been pushed and someone else has base their work on it, amending it might cause confusing for him/her. Remember, in Git there really is no such thing as "updating" or "amending" a commit, `--amend` will simply create a brand new commit – leaving the old commit as is. See [Does amending a commit change its hash?](https://blog.git-init.com/does-amending-a-commit-change-its-hash/)